# How to set borderRadius (rounded corners) in React Native Header Bar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v6, border-radius

I'm using [Native Stack Navigator v6](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/) and trying to add `borderBottomRightRadius` and `borderBottomLeftRadius` as shown below. It's working in Expo Web but not in iOS or Android, as shown in screenshot below.

[image: react native header border radius expo web vs. mobile]

I'd appreciate guidance on how to fix this, or if this is not the right approach, please suggest another way to achieve bottom rounded corners for the header bar.

```
      <HomeStack.Screen 
        name="HomeScreen" 
        component={HomeScreen} 
        options= {{
          headerTitle: "Home Screen",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#21ABA5',
            borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            background: 'transparent'
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
          },
          headerTintColor: 'white',
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
```

Comment: do you have an expo snack to share? it would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me edit my answer. If you don't want for web at all, you can create your own header. If you want to apply to all screens, add it to Stack.Navigator's ScreenOptions.

```
import { getHeaderTitle } from "@react-navigation/elements";

function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => {
            const title = getHeaderTitle(options, route.name);

            return (
              <MyHeader
                title={title}
                leftButton={
                  back ? (
                    <MyBackButton onPress={navigation.goBack} />
                  ) : undefined
                }
                style={options.headerStyle}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't need to support web at all. But your proposal for Android/iOS variant only adds a custom header **title** component. I don't see how that has any effect on the header bar itself, which is a parent component and the one responsible for the radius.

Comment: Hello, Rwzr Q, I believe my edited answer might help you.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but the reason I didn't opt for the custom header option is because than some of the advantages of the Native Stack are lost. From the docs: "Note that if you specify a custom header, the native functionality such as large title, search bar etc. won't work."

Comment: What would you say are the advantages of using Native Stack (with custom header) vs. using the JS-based Stack?

Comment: Stack has some advantages over Native Stack, but borderRadius is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

After further research turns out this is impossible.

Native Stack Navigator depends on native platform options which apparently don't support borderRadius out-of-the-box. The only option that can be affected via the `headerStyle` is `backgroundColor`.

Other options include using the [Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) instead of the Native Stack Navigator, or building an entirely custom header component. However, the latter loses most of built-in the advantages of the Native Stack Navigator. Thus, I'll be switching to the JS-based Stack Navigator which is far more customizable.